# Remove image from download cache

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross 3.1.1 and `MvxImageView` on iOS.

The `MvxImageView` load images from Urls and cache these. However, I want to update these images but it keeps loading the cached image.

I.e. when using Url like `www.lalalalalala.dk/bjar.png`. Then this image is updated from somewhere else. However the Url stays the same. It seems that the `MvxImageView` keeps the cached image and do not load the new one.

Is it possible to remove the cached image and force it to reload the image from the Url?

I tried taking a look at

```
var service = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxImageHelper<UIImage>>();
```

but I could not find anything useful.

---

UPDATE
I must say this gives me a bit of a headache. I found how to remove a image from the filesystem, however sometimes the image is stored in memory and therefore cannot be deleted. Any suggestions how to tackle that situation?

Comment: The DownloadCache currently has not implementation to delete single images.

Comment: Any suggestions for a workaround mr baron?

Comment: Either a. implement it and make a pull request, or b. look in the folder where it caches images and nuke the image yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I will go for the nuke first(my own idea as well) If time/work/space continuum allows it I will make a correct implementation later

Comment: I must say this gives me a bit of a headache. I found how to remove a image from the filesystem, however sometimes the image is stored in memory and therefore cannot be deleted. Any suggestions how to tackle that situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending (copy/paste) the image-cache - MvxImageCache and IMvxImageCache in mvvmcross and added these two methods.

```
    public void RemoveUrlFromCache(string url)
    {
        this.RunSyncOrAsyncWithLock(
            () =>
                {
                    Entry entry;
                    if (this._entriesByHttpUrl.TryGetValue(url, out entry))
                    {
                        this._entriesByHttpUrl.Remove(url);

                    }
                this._fileDownloadCache.RequestLocalFilePath(url, (stream) => this.DeleteFile(url, stream),
                    (exception) => this.ProcessError(url, exception));

                });
    }

    private void DeleteFile(string url, string filepath)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
        {
            var fileService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStore>();
            fileService.DeleteFile(filepath);
        }
    }
```

With This I am able to call the following in my subclassed Imageview in droid(touch is similar).

```
var cache = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxImageCache<Bitmap>>() as ImageCache<Bitmap>;;
            if (cache != null)
            {
                cache.RemoveUrlFromCache(_imageUrl);   
            }
```

I will do a pull request and hopefully they will take it in or do something similar